# expr command used to work and stopped

Tags: bash, date, math, solaris

I am on SunOS machine trying to get the date string of the past minute, yesterday I used this command I found on the internet

```
expr `date +%Y%m%d%k%M` - 1
```

which is worked just fine and I saw the output and this is the output I got from my session that is still opened:

```
bash-3.00$ expr `date +%Y%m%d%k%M` - 1
201303131641
```

Now I am trying to run this command on the same session and I got this output:

```
bash-3.00$ expr `date +%Y%m%d%k%M` - 1
expr: syntax error
```

My machine is running this OS:

```
bash-3.00$ uname -a
SunOS mySunOS 5.10 Generic_144488-11 sun4v sparc SUNW,Netra-T2000
```

I think there is some environmental variable or something that have been changed, can anyone help me out with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `%H` instead of `%k`. Yesterday it probably worked because the hour had double digits then. Note that this is not a good way to get the previous minute, because of what happens when the time is exactly on the hour.